# How to show how long user has been online on my app. "David, online for 12 minutes"

Tags: reactjs, date, time, local-storage, single-page-application

how to show how long the user has been online for.

In the header of messaging app it should look like:

"David has been online for 12 minutes", store it in local storage.

Since local storage allows us to store data only in String, I am having difficulties converting Date.

Answer (score 0):

To get the user's online status we can use browser Navigator API `window.navigator.onLine`. You can find more information in this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorOnLine/onLine).

To get the amount of time the user was online, add this `useEffect` in your App.js

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log(window.navigator.onLine);

    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      const sessionStartTime = localStorage.getItem("sessionStartTime");

      if (sessionStartTime) {
        const d1 = new Date(sessionStartTime);
        const d2 = new Date();
        const diff = d2.getTime() - d1.getTime();

        console.log(`User has been online for ${diff / (1000 * 60)} minutes`);
      }
    }, 1000 * 60);

    window.addEventListener("offline", function (e) {
      localStorage.setItem("sessionStartTime", "");
    });

    window.addEventListener("online", function (e) {
      localStorage.setItem("sessionStartTime", new Date().toString());
    });

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("online", () => {
        console.log("Removed online event listener");
      });
      window.removeEventListener("offline", () => {
        console.log("Removed offline event listener");
      });
      clearInterval(interval);
    };
  }, []);
```

You can change read interval as per the requirement